# How can i read and display info from multiple text files in 1 message box C#?

Tags: c#

So i have a application that uses check boxes and radio buttons to scan a computer for virus then have each anti virus create a log of its actions. What id like to do is (based on which check boxes (there's 5 total) are checked) have a message box pop up when its all done and have read each text file for a key word then read that line, for all 5 text files (if all 5 were created could be 1,2,3,4 or 5 of them). So when its all done it will just have 1 message box pop up with the info from all 5 text files 1 line each like "Panda found 5 viruses" next line "A Squared found 0 viruses" etc. then when the message box is closed, delete the text files. I know how to do this with 1 check box and 1 text file but i don't know how to do this with multiple check boxes and multiple text files. My single file reader works like this:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Panda.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("Number of files infected"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Panda " + line);
    }
}
file.Dispose();
System.IO.File.Delete("C:\\Panda.txt");
```

any help would be nice thanks. OH and C# .net 2.0 ONLY please

Comment: with the line MessageBox.Show(writer); i get the errors "the best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.show(string)' has some invalid arguments. and "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.StringWriter' to 'string'

Comment: worked almost perfectly except that i need some sort of error handling where as if there wont always be option 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 checked, some times i may be 1,2, and 5, OR it may only be 3. Where right now it looks for the 2 text files and if the first 1 cant be found it just errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringWriter to append the current line and display in Message Box at last

```
        string FirstPanda = "C:\\FirstPanda.txt";
        string SecondPanda = "C:\\SecondPanda.txt";


        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); // System.IO;
        System.IO.StreamReader file;

        if (firstCheckBox.IsChecked)  
        {
            if (File.Exists(FirstPanda))
            {
                file = new System.IO.StreamReader(FirstPanda);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("Number of files infected"))
                    {

                        writer.WriteLine("Panda " + line);
                    }
                }
                file.Close();
                System.IO.File.Delete(FirstPanda);
            }
        }

        if (secondCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            if (File.Exists(SecondPanda))
            {
                file = new StreamReader(SecondPanda);

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("Number of files infected"))
                    {

                        writer.WriteLine("Panda " + line);
                    }
                }
                file.Close();

                System.IO.File.Delete(SecondPanda);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(writer.ToString());
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: worked almost perfectly except that i need some sort of error handling where as if there wont always be option 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 checked, some times i may be 1,2, and 5, OR it may only be 3. Where right now it looks for the 2 text files and if the first 1 cant be found it just errors.

Comment: How can you make it so it checks to see if they exist before it reads them? because if say Panda.txt isnt there but NextPand.txt is... it just throws an error

Comment: Use File.Exists(path) to check  if they exist.

Comment: ok yea File.Exists(path) seemed to do the trick thanks but, now how do i modify the 'if (line.Contains(""))' line to read more than one line for just one of the files? Because one of the txt files needs to have 4 lines read it needs to look for the word "Found" then read the next 5 lines (5 because the first after found is a space)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding the question right, but if I rephrase it. You want to process the 5 files and when all done show a summary of what was found?

If so why not simply do this

```
public void ProcessFiles()
{
  var resultText = new StringBuilder();

  if (PandaCheckBox.Checked)
  {
    var result = DoPandaProcessing(); // Read file and do whatever here
    resultText.Append(result.ResultMessage);
  }

  if (Process2CheckBox.Checked)
  {
    var result = DoProcess2Processing();
    if (resultText.Length > 0)
    {
      resultText.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    resultText.Append(result.ResultMessage);
  }

  MessageBox.Show(resultText.ToString());
}
```

And just because I don't like how you dispose (ie you don't on any exception), implement the methods like this

```
public ProcessResult DoPandaProcessing()
{
  using (var file = File.OpenText("filename.txt"))
  {
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       if (line.Contains("Number of files infected"))
       {
          return new ProcessResult { Status = Status.Success, ResultMessage = "Panda " + line };
       }
    }

    return new ProcessResult { Status = Status.Failure, ResultMessage = "Panda: No result found!" }
  }
}
```